# Can’t add Mediainfo to Open With list (using Nemo or mimeopen)

Tags: mime-type, nemo, file-association

[While researching this problem I have found a work-around, but I’m still curious to see if anyone can explain why this is happening.]

In the past I’m certain I’d added `mediainfo-gui` to the Open With list using Nemo. I’ve no idea what Nemo actually does when you do this, but it was working fine in Nemo, Thunar and Nautilus. Recently I noticed the association had disappeared, but when I tried to add it back it didn’t work. I tried doing it via command line, using `mimeopen -d` on a target file. This worked, but when I set the default back to the program I wanted, Mediainfo disappeared again.

I wonder if part of the problem is that `/usr/share/application/mediainfo-gui.desktop` has a `Mimetype=` line that contains no mimetypes? My workaround was to copy mimetypes from vlc.desktop (possibly overkill?) and then run `sudo update-desktop-database`.

[Ubuntu 14.04.4]

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and created what I believe is the proper Nemo-specific solution: create a file `~/.local/share/nemo/actions/mediainfo.nemo_action` with the content

```
[Nemo Action]

Name=MediaInfo

Quote=double

Icon-Name=mediainfo

Exec=mediainfo-gui %F

Selection=notnone

Mimetypes=audio/*;video/*;
```

This will make it show up in the context menu the way it does with most other file managers. Of course a more generic way would be to add those two mimetypes to the .desktop file, which puts it in the Open With list.